# Extra character appearing on string in C Program

Tags: arrays

I'm working on a homework problem that involves making a word search program. The letter grid and words are taken from an input file. I have the grid stored in an array and I want to turn the rows and columns into discrete strings so that I can use the strstr function on them to find a word. I wanted to test that I created a string properly and I'm finding it has two extra characters on the end of it. Why is this? BTW The size variable is equal to 5 and was used to define the dimensions of the array.

```
char line[size+1];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    line[i] = grid[0][i];
    printf("character %c \n", grid[0][i]);
}
line[size+1] = '\0';


printf("test string %s \n", line);
```

Here's the output including the printed word grid.

```
A L P H A
B O F L A
B C P Z T
B H H A E
A T X Y B
test string ALPHA'
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with strings to denote the end of a string array the last element should always contain a null character '\0' maybe you havent assigned that because of which it is having garbage value in that place

P.S. array size is always n+1 of the actual string so that it can contain the termination character

Comment: My code doesn't show it but I mentioned it in the text, I added a null character and I still have an extra garbage character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You add the null character at an index outside of the char array. Array indexes begin with zero but you treat it like the first index is 1.
As an example, this outputs "test string ALPHAX" since the null character is added outside of the array and not in the last element:

```
int size = 5;
  char line[size+1];
  int i;

  line[0] = 'A';
  line[1] = 'L';
  line[2] = 'P';
  line[3] = 'H';
  line[4] = 'A';
  line[5] = 'X';

  line[size+1] = '\0'; // size+1 is 6

printf("test string %s \n", line);
```

Change `line[size+1] = '\0';` to `line[size] = '\0';` in your code like below and it should work as expected.

```
char line[size+1];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    line[i] = grid[0][i];
    printf("character %c \n", grid[0][i]);
}
line[size] = '\0';


printf("test string %s \n", line);
```